# ImportError: cannot import name 'HTTPSHandler' from 'urllib.request' for windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, urllib

I found 0 topics about this issue for Windows, only for Ubuntu, MAc etc.
When I try to install any package via Pycharm, e.g. urllib, matplotlib, heidi, I get the exact same error message as below.
Project interpreter is Anaconda Python 3.7.
Any idea how this can solved?

```
Error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Download\PROGIK\Charm Community Edition 2018.3.5\helpers\packaging_tool.py", line 73, in run_pip
    runpy.run_module(module_name, run_name='__main__', alter_sys=True)
  File "E:\Download\PROGIK\Anaconda\lib\runpy.py", line 201, in run_module
    mod_name, mod_spec, code = _get_module_details(mod_name)
  File "E:\Download\PROGIK\Anaconda\lib\runpy.py", line 142, in _get_module_details
    return _get_module_details(pkg_main_name, error)
  File "E:\Download\PROGIK\Anaconda\lib\runpy.py", line 109, in _get_module_details
    __import__(pkg_name)
  File "E:\Download\PROGIK\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pip\__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
    from pip.vcs import git, mercurial, subversion, bazaar  # noqa
  File "E:\Download\PROGIK\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pip\vcs\subversion.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pip.index import Link
  File "E:\Download\PROGIK\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pip\index.py", line 30, in <module>
    from pip.wheel import Wheel, wheel_ext
  File "E:\Download\PROGIK\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pip\wheel.py", line 35, in <module>
    from pip._vendor.distlib.scripts import ScriptMaker
  File "E:\Download\PROGIK\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\distlib\scripts.py", line 14, in <module>
    from .compat import sysconfig, detect_encoding, ZipFile
  File "E:\Download\PROGIK\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\distlib\compat.py", line 66, in <module>
    from urllib.request import (urlopen, urlretrieve, Request, url2pathname,
ImportError: cannot import name 'HTTPSHandler' from 'urllib.request' (E:\Download\PROGIK\Anaconda\lib\urllib\request.py)
```

Edit: with pip I have only problem with matplotlib, which is another topic:
[Cannot install matplotlib. Fatal error LNK1181, Visual Studio fail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57495471/cannot-install-matplotlib-fatal-error-lnk1181-visual-studio-fail)
Simply went into packages folder and deleted matplotlib package manually because could not make it display graphs in Jupyter (didnt try in Pycharm). Trying to reinstall it now,  hopefully it will fix the issue.

Comment: have you tried installing it via pip?

Comment: With pip only problem is with matplotlib, thats the one I want to install. Edited post above for more info.

Comment: there can be naming conflict. with you script file or another module. Besides, by default, matplotlib is already installed in Anaconda distribution.

Comment: Simply went into packages folder and deleted it manually because could not make it display graphs in Jupyter (didnt try in Pycharm). Trying to reinstall it now,  hopefully it will fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

To install packages whithin anaconda environment under Windows10, you should use "Anaconda prompt" (find it in win menu)
It starts (Base) venv by default and installs packages in it. Therefore using Python interpreter distributed with Anaconda you will be able to import them with no side actions.

Besides matplotlib is installed there by default

Comment: Edit: with Anaconda prompt pip I have only problem with matplotlib, which is another topic, it can be seen in the top post in the edited section.
Simply went into packages folder and deleted matplotlib package manually because could not make it display graphs in Jupyter (didnt try in Pycharm). Trying to reinstall it now, hopefully it will fix the issue.